# If recently added/edited

Tags: channel-entries

I wish to display images from channel entries and if they have been created/edited within the last 14 days I want to add another image on top.

What would be the logic for detecting whether the entry was new or not?

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to use the display limit functions in ExpressionEngine's channel entries tag. Like

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="images" display_by="day" limit="14" orderby="edit_date"}
  <div class="display">{image}</div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

You can learn more about using the `display_by` parameter using options other than the standard `display_by="number"` in the **[User Guide](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#display-by)** *Channel Entries Tag*.

Also, if you want to include **both** edit and entry dates, then using `order_by` edit date will probably work best, since new entries should have the same entry and edit date, while edited entries will just have the most recent edit date. Otherwise the standard option is `order_by="entry_date"`.